# The texture is correct in render and uv but not in texture paint. How can I edit the correct texture paint?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

[image]

The texture paint is the only one that is wrong. Render and shading are correct but I can't correct it in paint plus every time I do try to paint it will paint on the wrong material.

I have two collections, one for the face and the other for the hair and the materials for them both. The face material is on the hair mesh while not being assigned to it.

---

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've selected *Mode > Material* in the *N panel > Tool > Texture Slots*, if you've selected *Single Image* you are painting on the selected image which may not be the good one:

[image]

Comment: Bingo, this was the answer